# Insert data into table using queue

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel queue function to auto insert data into a database table. The data will be auto-saved if the table has no record inside. My first step is able to insert data into a table then only do validation. however, my data seems can't insert to database.

My Queue function

```
public function save_sale_price_on_the_fly($job, $data)
    {
        $selling_price = array_get($data, 'price');
        $item_id = array_get($data, 'item_id');
        $payee_id = array_get($data, 'payee_id');

            DB::table('customer_products')
            ->where('product_id', '=', $item_id)
            ->where('customer_id', '=', $payee_id)
            ->where('different_price', '=', $selling_price)
            ->first();
    }
```

My model

```
static::saved(function($model)
        {
            if (!$model->item_id && $model->payee_id && $model->price) {
                Queue::push('InvoiceQueue@save_sale_price_on_the_fly', $model->toArray());
            }
        });
```

The item,payee and price is returned from another table. I'm trying to pass this 3 value into my customer_products table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queue function isn't saving any data, It is just attempting to retrieve data.

You need to explicitly save the data.

Change your query to something like:

```
DB::table('customer_products')
    ->insert([
        'product_id' => $item_id,
        'customer_id' => $payee_id,
        'different_price' => $selling_price
     ]);
```

Laravel 4 documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.